# Concavity/Convexity, QuasiConcavity,QuasiConvexity.

Tags: convex-analysis, economics

I am given the piecewise {x^2 for x>0 and x for x<=0} and I am asked to find out if it is Convex/Strictly Convex/QuasiConvex/Strictly QuasiConvex and the same 4 for Concavity.

This is more of a "Is my thought process right?" Because not having a teacher due to covid is making this very challenging. (I am mostly guessing on the Quasi's)

I believe it can not be convex because the line between X=-0.1 and X=0.1 is below the graph

I believe it can not be concave because the line between X=0 and X=0.1 is above the graph

I believe it can not be strictly convex because it is not convex

I believe it can not be strictly concave because it is not concave

I believe it is all 4 forms of QuasiComplex/Concave because both the ABS Min and Max are the endpoints, so no value C in between them will be Higher or Lower than both endpoints.

If I am wrong on any of these please let me know (Don't give me the answer right away please! I want to be able to figure it out!)

Answer (score 1):

> "Is my thought process right?"

Yes.

You can also easily prove that if a function is (strictly) monotonic then it is both (strictly) quasiconvex and quasiconcave.

Comment: Thanks! We actually haven't gone over monotonic functions yet (which I'm pretty sure is weird because everywhere I looked for help mentioned it)

Comment: @Mike Do you know what an "increasing function" means?

Comment: Yes! I figured out what Monotonic is along with increasing, which would explain why my thought process of the end points being an absolute min and max would have to be quasi concave and quasi convex. But I also don't want to use logic he hasn't taught us yet, and he has exclusively taught us the formal definitions for determining them.